# Allow Bootstrap columns to use unoccupied space width within a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

If you'd run the following code and hover the rendered elements, you'll see that there's an unoccupied space between the `left` and `middle` elements:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="left">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">3</div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="middle">get me lefter, to the unoccupied space</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

... Here's what you'd see (in purple is the unoccupied space):

[image]

Is it possible to add CSS that will robustly tell `left` to let `middle` use the unoccupied space, *if such exists*?
Also, does Bootstrap has some built-in CSS for that?

Comment: Can I restructure the HTML at all?

Comment: @Kameron, I rather not, I'm looking for a CSS solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you defined the column that will be used (`col-sm-3`).

With your constraint (not restructuring the HTML), you could just modify the `#left` div's class to `col-sm-auto` which tells `#left` to occupy only the space it needed so that there is no unused space and `#middle` could occupy the old unused space.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-auto" id="left">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto">1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-auto">2</div>
        <div class="col-sm-auto">3</div>
      </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="middle">get me lefter, to the unoccupied space</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" id="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the class `col-sm-auto` on item 1, 2, and 3. Also tell them to use the width they needed instead of defining 1 column out of 12 so that no unused space made.